PrimeNg editor: Value is not showing form the formControl
I have a component, which contains a formGroup which consists of two controls:
`enFormGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      titleEn: ['test', Validators.required],
      textEn: ['hello world', Validators.required],
    });`

In my html, I am using the editor from primeNg and I bound the formControl like this:
 `<div>
      <form [formGroup]="enFormGroup">
        <p-editor formControlName="textEn"></p-editor>
      </form>
    </div>`

the text 'hello world' is not showing up when I open the component.
Here are the versions of primeng and quill:
primeng: 13.2.1
quill: 2.0.1
StackBlitz example
Could someone help me with this please?

@Yazan please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens

@NarenMurali sure thing, here is a fast stackblitz implementation:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jgxuom?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Feditor%2Feditor.component.ts,src%2Feditor%2Feditor.component.html&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter

I had the same error and the solution was change quill's version.
npm uninstall quill
npm install quill@1.3.7

Works wonders, here's some more info on the underlying issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/14721
